# Django testing - group object not working when using factory_boy

Tags: django, django-testing, factory-boy

I'm trying to streamline my testing by using factory_boy. I would like to test views that depend on some group permissions. If I write my test by creating a user and group in `setUpTestData`, I can get the test to work. However, if I create the user and group using factory_boy, it doesn't look like the permissions are set in the test.

view

```
@method_decorator([login_required, teacher_required], name='dispatch')
class GradeBookSetupCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    raise_exceptions = True
    permission_required = 'gradebook.change_gradebooksetup'
    permission_denied_message = "You don't have access to this."

    form_class = GradeBookSetupForm
    model = GradeBookSetup

    success_url = "/gradebook/"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        try:
            obj = GradeBookSetup.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            return obj
        except:
            pass
```

The permission problem is from the PermissionRequiredMixin and `permission_required`.  There is also a permission in the decorator but that is working fine.

Here is a test that works:

```
class GradeBookSetupTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username='teacher1',
            email='tester@email.com',
            password='tester123'
        )
        cls.user.is_active = True
        cls.user.is_teacher = True
        cls.user.save()
        teacher_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='teacher')
        teacher_group = Group.objects.get(name='teacher')

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(
            app_label='gradebook', model='gradebooksetup')
        # get all permssions for this model
        perms = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
        for p in perms:
            teacher_group.permissions.add(p)

        cls.user.groups.add(teacher_group)
        cls.user.save()
        print(cls.user.groups.filter(name='teacher').exists())
        my_g = cls.user.groups.all()
        for g in my_g:
            print(g)
        cls.gradeb = GradeBookSetupFactory(user=cls.user)

    def test_signup_template(self):
        self.client.login(username='teacher1', password='tester123')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('gradebook:gradebooksetup'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'gradebook/gradebooksetup_form.html')
```

This test creates a user, creates a group, assigns the permissions to the group, adds the user to the group and the asserts pass. The print statements return `True` and `teacher`, which is what I expect.

The following code using factory_boy to create the  user and group:

```
class SubscribedGroupFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = auth_models.Group

    name = 'teacher'


class TeacherFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser

    is_teacher = True
    is_active = True
    username = 'teacher1'
    password = 'tester123'

    @factory.post_generation
    def groups(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            return

        if extracted:
            for group in extracted:
                self.groups.add(group)
                print(group)

class GradeBookSetupTests(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.user = TeacherFactory.create(
            groups=(SubscribedGroupFactory.create(),))
        teacher_group = Group.objects.get(name='teacher')

        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(
            app_label='gradebook', model='gradebooksetup')
        # get all permssions for this model
        perms = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
        for p in perms:
            teacher_group.permissions.add(p)

        cls.user.groups.add(teacher_group)
        cls.user.save() # I'm not sure if this is needed
        print(cls.user.groups.filter(name='teacher').exists())
        my_g = cls.user.groups.all()
        for g in my_g:
            print(g)
        cls.gradeb = GradeBookSetupFactory(user=cls.user)

    def test_signup_template(self):
        self.client.login(username='teacher1', password='tester123')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('gradebook:gradebooksetup'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'gradebook/gradebooksetup_form.html')
```

When this test is run, the print statements also print `True` and `teacher`, which makes me think the user/group is ok. However, the permissions are not working and the test fails (404 redirect, because the user doesn't have permission to view the page). Something is different about how the group interacts with the permission.

Ideally I would also add the permissions to the group within factory_boy but I haven't figured out how to do that either.

Comment: Can you assert that the output of `self.client.login` is `True`? I suspect you are not authenticating properly because you are not saving the password correctly

Comment: @Iain Shelvington You're correct, `self.client.login` is `False` when I use factory_boy.